# Getting component from Fragment crashes app

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android and learning from developer.android.com. As per their tutorial I am trying to get my textView from the Fragment like this.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState
) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View fragmentFirstLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    
    // Get the text view
    showCountTextView = (TextView) fragmentFirstLayout.findViewById(R.id.textview_first);
    return fragmentFirstLayout;
}
```

And this builds successfully but crashes as soon as launched. Any idea what is wrong. The log says like this.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.example.myapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #8 in com.example.myapp:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
```

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace

Comment: I suspect that there is something you haven't initialized and I would suggest you edit the question to show entire fragment code and the entire stack trace.